# Inconsistent unit tests - failing in test suite, passing separated

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit, integration-testing

I have a unit tests for Zend Framework controllers extending [`Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Test/PHPUnit/Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase.html).

The tests are dispatching an action, which forwards to another action, like this:

```
// AdminControllerTest.php

public testAdminAction()    
   $this->dispath('/admin/index/index');
   // forwards to login page
   $this->assertModule('user');
   $this->assertController('profile');
   $this->assertController('login');
   $this->assertResponseCode(401);
}

// NewsControllerTest.php

public testIndexAction()
{
     $this->dispatch('/news/index/index');
     $this->assertModule('news');
     $this->assertController('index');
     $this->assertController('index');
     $this->assertResponseCode(200);

}
```

Both of the tests are passing when they are run as a seperate tests.
When I run them in the same test suite, the second one fails.
Instead dispatching `/news/index/index` the previous request is dispatched (user module).

How to trace this bug? Looks like I have some global state somewhere in the application, but I'm unable do debug this. How can I dump the objects between the tests in the suite? `setUpBefore/AfterClass` are static, so there are no so many data about the object instances.

I know this is a kind of *guess what* question. It's hard to provide reliable data here, because they would took to much place, so feel free to ask for details.

The whole unit test setup is more or less like described in: [Testing Zend Framework MVC Applications - phly, boy, phly](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/182-Testing-Zend-Framework-MVC-Applications.html) or [Testing Zend Framework Controllers « Federico Cargnelutti](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2008/12/27/testing-zend-framework-controllers/).

### Solution:

I've determined the issue (after a little nap). The problem was not in unit test setup, but in the tested code.

I use different ACL objects based on module name. Which one to use was determined by static call to action helper, which cached the result in a private static variable to speed things up. This cache was executed only when run in a test suite. I just need more unit tests for this code :)

(I'm sorry for such a rubbish post, but I've stuck with this for a day and I hoped someone else experienced similar kind of this Heisenbug with unit tests in general)

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but it is possible that when you run them separately you are running setUp() for each individual tests and in the test suite you have a setUp() method that might be only running once before all the tests take place. I am not familiar with the technologies you are using though, but just pointing out a possible generic source of problems. Good luck!

Comment: I assume you're using Zend's `ControllerTestCase`. Can you post your bootstrap code, both in the test case and what it calls? Are you using own base test case that subclasses CTC and which the test cases subclass?

Comment: Test interference is a common headache that must be addressed on a case-by-case basis. For our projects I created `SetupAction`s registered with a `TestListener` implementation that perform global `setUp` and `tearDown` operations for resetting static state after each test. We use them in cases where it's too much bother to track down which tests end up setting these states, and they cost so little to reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try clearing`request` and `response` objects before dispatching each action, like this:

```
$this->resetRequest()
     ->resetResponse()
     ->dispatch('/news/index/index');
```

Comment: This does not help. I've already reset them in different places.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for taking time to respond. I've updated my original post with the actual solution.